# The tag [100ms] doesn't seem to be a unit of time any more

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

I just stumbled over the newly created tag [100ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/100ms).

It has created by a user who edited two questions ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73047816/flutter-error-superclass-has-no-method-named-initstate), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70480890/angular-12-showing-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-pe)).

They also [suggested a tag wiki except](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32298107).

It seems like the user intended the tag to be used for a site called [100ms.live](https://www.100ms.live/) as both questions edited link to that site.

I would say that the name [100ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/100ms) is confusing with the time unit millisecond and would probably be used for questions about anything with 100 milliseconds in it (e.g., repeating something every 100 milliseconds).

Since [100ms.live presents itself as a "cloud platform" and seems to be (at least in the context of Stack Overflow) mostly seems about an API and SDK](https://docs.100ms.live/), I therefore suggest to rename the tag to something like [100ms.live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/100ms.live), [100ms.live-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/100ms.live-api), [100ms.live-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/100ms.live-sdk) (since they also mentioned their tag being about the 100ms SDK in their tag excerpt) or [100ms.live-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/100ms.live-platform)

Apparently, [the user who created the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1469222/arjunattam) seems to [work at 100ms](https://arjun.is/). They may intended to [use Stack Overflow as a support service](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support).

Comment: This tag doesn't seem like it needs to exist...at least not on those questions.  It seems incidental to them at most.

Comment: I'd like to have a word with whoever thought naming their service like this was a good idea...

Comment: Unfortunately it is the site which is named 100ms.live, but the linked page itself calls the service '100ms'. Truly a terrible name. But I guess you do what you must to disambiguate tags, so 100ms.live seems like a good compromise.

Comment: The NPM name is "@100mslive/hms-video". I assume users would be familiar with "live" being in the name even if they've never visited the website.

Comment: If there are only 2 questions tagged with it, and they are from the same user, does the tag really need to exist at all? It doesn't sound like something that's that popular on here  so why is it needed *at all*?

Comment: I'd like to echo the sentiment that this is an awfully named service; on that note, considering one of their packages contains 100mslive, I'm renaming the tag to that. 100ms employees/contributors: if you have a different preferred tag name, ping me (as long as it isn't [tag:100ms], that doesn't work)

Comment: And this is why people creating tags should be aware when they create tags that have generic namings otherwise.

Comment: At least this tag only existed for [100ms].